# Change a datetime2 column to date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to convert a column in SQL Server Express from a `datetime2(7)` format to a `date` format.

I have tried `convert`, a number of different ways with brackets and parenthesis but I'm having issues either with 'binding' or syntax.

`dbo.stateByStatehood.annexDate`

```
USE bigCity

--1.
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2(7), GETDATE()) annexDate;

--2.
SELECT CONVERT (datetime2(7)), stateByStatehood.annexDate date
```

Comment: What issues are you having? Aside from a missing bracket? The official documentation tells you how to correctly use convert. And there if also format if convert doesn't meet your needs. Normally however you format your data for display in the front end, not the database.

Comment: Your first query does not do what you say you want. It converts the return value of GETDATE (which is datetime) to datetime2. The second query generates an error - which you did not post. But is also logically does the same as the first query. CONVERT takes the second argument and converts it to the type specified in the first argument.

Comment: @DaleK Ok, this makes sense.  I am trying to change the formatting of the column instead of formating the data for display.  I guess that was really the question, that I asked in a weird way.

So just so I have this right;  Don't try to format the columns, format the output.  Is that the right way to think of it?

Comment: @SMor  You're right, I didn't put a lot into what I actually did.  I worked on it for a couple of hours so I don't have a lot of the stuff I tried.  Suffice it to say, I am trying to format the column attributes instead of formatting the output for the data.  I think I understand how it works now, but thanks for digging deeper.

Comment: @robertmullins datetimes if stored correctly, using the datetime2 datatype are not stored formatted, they are stored using an internal binary format. It's just SQL server uses a default format when you query them in order they make sense to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for cast to date datatype as given below:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) as annexDate;

SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) as annexDate
```

| annexDate |
| --- |
| 2021-08-27 |

Comment: You can do it using the CAST ()  as mentioned above

Comment: so will this re-format the date stored in the columns?  Or will it just trim the output when running a query?

Comment: It will convert into DATE datatype. DATE datatype contains only the date component of the datetime value.